# How to set Thread_UseAllCpuGroups enabled="true" without separate config file

Tags: .net, config

I need to set Thread_UseAllCpuGroups and GCCpuGroup to true for my .NET FrameWork 4.5 application but I do *not* want to deploy my application with a separate app.config file to accomplish this.

So far I have found/come up with the following solutions:

**Solution 1**

Instead of using the config file, the the global environment variables:

set complus_GCCpuGroup=1
set COMPlus_Thread_UseAllCpuGroups=1

I don't really like this because I don't really want to make system global change for something that only concerns my application. Also, it seems these must be set *before* the application is started. A solution for that might be to check for the value of those variables and if they are not set, set them and instantly restart the application.

**Solution 2**

Let the executable copy itself to a temp folder, extract the config file from an embedded resource into that same temp folder and then run the copy from the temp folder and exit.

**Solution 3 (perhaps)**

Migrate to a newer version of .NET Framework or even .NET where perhaps there is a better, more self-contained way to enable this (I believe I have read that later .NET versions have this in a .json file. But I'd rather not migrate to a different .NET version at this time, not for something like this.

**My questions:**

1. Will any of the above ideas work
2. Is there a better (as in cleaner) solution?